# How to type function signature and array with that same structure using one type

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation

```
type fnArgs = [string, number];

function test(a: string, b: number): void {}

const x: fnArgs = ['a', 2];

test(...x);
```

What I have is that the values passed to function **test** come from an array **x** ([demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgdgQQE4HMDOUC8UDabhICWcKANFHAK4C2ARhEgLoDcAUKzJXAMbCED2cKMAj4AFAEMAXFHxES5WjKp0GAShkA3foQAmUAN4Bfdt0H4oADxnxk6LLgDkEx%20QBMLdiPEA6P5bU2dlYgA)). The nice thing is that Typescript can figure out that the structure of the array matches the function signature in combination with the spread operator.

My quetion now is, can I use type **fnArgs** for the function signature as well? Because I have to define **string, number** twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructure your tuple inline:

```
function test(...[a, b]: fnArgs): void {}
```

You can also do this:

```
function test(...args: fnArgs): void {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function test(a: fnArgs[0], b: fnArgs[1]): void {}
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=12#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgdgQQE4HMDOUC8UDabhICWcKANFHAK4C2ARhEgLoDcAsAFAcyVwDGwhAPZwowCPgAUAQwBcsRKjQ4ADI3K058ZOhwBGRgEo5AN0GEAJlADeAXw4dew-FAAemheiy4A5FO-kAJhZ7djFJADpIlwNmIA)

It's a bit repetitive, but at least if you change `fnArgs`' elements' types that change will be reflected in the function signature.

---

Just FWIW, you can do the same sort of thing when the type is an interface. For instance, if you have a function that retrieves something from somewhere by `id`:

```
interface Foo {
    id: string;
    // ...other fields here
}

function makeFoo(id: Foo["id"]): Foo {
    // ...
}
```

(Note: `Foo.id` won't work, it has to be the brackets form with quotes.)

If `id` gets changed from `string` to `number`, that change will be reflected in the function's signature.